# Run-time library dependency (outdated) and installed library versions do not match - Linux

Tags: dependencies, libraries

Recently I got a new problem: my system cannot find `libplacebo.so.208`, but simply because the current version is newer.

This is my currently installed version of the package libplacebo:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libplacebo*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17  2 jan 18:47 /usr/lib/libplacebo.so -> libplacebo.so.229
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 768840  2 jan 18:47 /usr/lib/libplacebo.so.229
```

Many softwares (ffmpeg, zzzfm, ...) will only look after the version 208:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/zzzfm
        [...]
        libplacebo.so.208 => not found
        [...]
```

Why does it behave like this? These packages/programs worked like a charm even yesterday, and I update all my packages daily.
I tried to reinstall `libplacebo`, without any change.
It is quite strange, since it seems like every package having a dependency on `libplacebo` is now unable to find it.

The only trick working I found is to create a symbolic link from `libplacebo.so.208` to `libplacebo.so`. I find it a bit dirty, and would like to know why there is this version mismatch and if I can do anything about that (except creating the symlink like already said).

Could I have broke some things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the only application that you are using that requires that version if the library, then it's fine.

If you want to be extra safe, then you can compile libplacebo 228 from source and add the directory containing `libplacebo.so.208` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by creating a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` such as `libplacebo.conf` and then run `ldconfig`. That will have the particular library available immediately and at login.

Comment: I just saw that the version mismatch is a recurrent problem with many software, including ffmpeg. It seems like every package with a dependency on `libplacebo` is now unable to find the library. Does your answer is still accurary (sorry for the update)? I'm editing a bit my question right now.

Comment: @TheBigBadBoy Yes. That will add the directory containing the needed library to the environment for no matter whom and no matter what applications need it. That is the purpose of it.